# How to get cold air from one room to another

Tags: air-conditioning

This is the very rough outline of my flat:

```
    +----------+
    |Bedroom   |
    W           \
+---+----------+
|Ba |Living
|lc |room
|on |
|y  |
+---+----------+
```

There is no window on the living room just the sliding balcony door. The only window is in the bedroom (the kitchen connecting to the living room and the bathroom are totally windowless). I could buy a portable AC unit to make at least the bedroom bearable but how could I get the air from the bedroom into the living room? Cutting a duct sized hole in the drywall is possible of course but gosh it'd be very ugly.

If I got a long enough duct extension (I found a twenty feet one), would it work 
with a portable AC? I could put a 14000 BTU unit in the tiny entranceway next to the bedroom door so it would cool both rooms.

I have thought of putting a water cooled air conditioner in the kitchen but a) I have no idea where to buy one in Vancouver, BC b) in light of Montreal just banning them what's the chance they are legal.

Comment: How does the heat for the two rooms work?

Comment: Check into mini-split multiple room units.

Comment: @Tyson i forgot to say -- absolutely no drilling of external walls.

Comment: "Water cooled air conditioners" don't work well and don't work at all if the ambient humidity is high.

Comment: @JimStewart that's an evaporative cooler. Totally different to what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used temperature controlled fans in the past with a covers to transfer heat from the lower floor where there was a high efficiency wood stove to the upper floor. You could do the same thing in the wall using return air grates to cover the fan, the most expensive part of the project was the fancy window fan I used that both low and high temp cutouts and could vary the flow by using 1 or both fans. I don't. Remember the brand but it was expensive ~$125 for a fan but it has been in place for 14 or 15 years. I did put an outlet in the cavity so it looked like a return air vent in the downstairs and fancy brass heat registers upstairs I think it looks great and it moves the air quite Well, I think this would work in your case also.

Comment: The actual shape is much more complicated than the simple ASCII drawing, I found the floorplans https://i.imgur.com/ht3GNKc.png mine is S.L. 29 and the red lines mark the internal walls between bedroom and living room. I marked with a red arrow a perfect spot where to drill. his spot is not visible from most of the place and has power available and is very close to where the AC will be -- the 2.48 long section next to it has the only sliding window in the entire flat. Also by placing the AC next to the window where it belongs I can use a double hose unit. Thanks, this is the perfect solution.

Comment: I wanted to post this works. Today is the first day I have the system on, a gigantic 14000 BTU dual hose Haier AC in the bedroom, a super quiet Panasonic bathroom fan pushing the air to the other room, it's only 0.3 sones and 150 CFM.