# Dehumidifier to help a portable AC?

Tags: air-conditioning, dehumidifier

I have asked [How to get cold air from one room to another](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/144170/41478) now I am thinking, the AC will be in the bedroom but what if I set up a dehumidifier (perhaps with a pump) in the kitchen connected directly into the drain? This last week mid day we had 60-70% humidity with 30 C temperatures and 90% humidity during the night although only 20C temperature outside. From what I read, it seems portable ACs struggle in high humidity to keep the air cold, perhaps this would help? Or it's taking air from the outside anyways and this doesn't matter?

Comment: Ah. So both ACs take the inside air and cool that anyways -- they don't cool and dumpthe outside air. Got it.

Comment: Deleted my comment that a portable dehumidifier would help an a/c cool a room. I don't think this is the case. A portable dehumidifier is a net heat source and would warm the room.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to put a two hose portable a/c in the living room you could vent it out the sliding glass door by getting one of those pet door panels that fits in the sliding glass door. You would use the pet door as the opening for the hoses.

Comment: Not a chance strata would allow this. I am only hoping they will allow for a portable AC (I asked for permission already) but changing the external look of the building by adding a new 'column' to the balcony side ? That won't happen -- and might even require a city permit. No way. Strata routinely refuses new owners who wants to replace their windows even if they would be painted the same color. Once again, I believe that has something to do with the look of the building. I hope a portable A/C vent not being permament will get through.

Comment: Then your best bet would be a two-hose portable a/c venting out the bedroom window and a fan in the doorway of the bedroom transferring air from bedroom to the living room.

Comment: Yes we cleared this in the other thread: two hose A/C in the bedroom and drill the wall between the bedroom and living room. On it! Strata council meeting on Thursday then I will call...I do not even know who, HVAC? Drywaller? Electrician? We will see who takes it.

Comment: What size hole would you want to make in the wall between the bedroom and the living room? You could no doubt put a special exhaust fan on the hole which would force air from the bedroom to the living room, but this would be non-standard, possibly noisy, and reduce privacy of the bedroom. Just opening the bedroom door and putting a "tower fan" in or beside the doorway blowing air into the living room would be a better first attempt.

Comment: I personally plan to get one of these tower fans improve local cooling in our central a/c house: https://www.target.com/p/honeywell-quiet-set-8-speed-tower-fan-oscillating/-/A-12110209

Comment: I have a Vornado184 right next to me, not one feet from me. It makes sitting in this chair kind of OK but going anywhere else in the flat is a jungle expedition.

Comment: It looks like the Vornado184 circulates air in all directions. So it is designed to serve the function of a ceiling fan, but if you want to direct the air flow in a single direction another type of tower would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Dryer air does contain less heat energy, and therefore would cool more readily. The real benefit, though, is in comfort. 74 degree air at 50% humidity cools skin more rapidly and feels much better than air at 80% humidity. In fact, you may find that you can tolerate a higher temperature if you have drier air. Your home will also smell better and you'll have much less mildew.

Answer (score 1):

A dehumidifier is essentially just an air conditioner that re-warms the air before blowing it back into the room. If your goal is to cool the room the additional step of re-warming the air is superfluous. When water condenses it releases heat, so the cooling coils in a dehumidifier absorb that heat. It results in cool water going down the drain. The air that comes out of a humidifier is slightly warmer than the air that goes in. Energy will be spent removing humidity which the a/c will have to make up for in re-cooling the air.  It will always end up as a net energy loss.

Before the edit I suggested an indoor a/c. I know they *make* indoor air conditioners, but the idea of an a/c is to move heat from indoors to outdoors, so I really don't know how an indoor a/c functions. The only possible way I can imagine them working is by *evaporating* water. Since your environment is humid it will already be pretty close to saturation, so that method would be extremely inefficient.

It sounds like your real problem is circulation, since you only have one window available. But I don't think a dehumidifier is going to do anything for you. The air conditioner itself is the best dehumidifier you can get.

Comment: I am getting a portable a/c but the kitchen has no windows and I thought literally pumping excess moisture away would help the portable A/C in the next room trying to cool the entire flat.

Comment: The dehumidifier would remove moisture in the air which would make the a/c more effective in cooling, but the dehumidifier is an overall power consumer and so would be a heat source in the room. One of the products of the dehumidifier is chilled water and this is *dumped* down a drain.  The most efficient cooling is a properly sized a/c. A dehumidifier is used to dry a room after a water leak or if there is a constant source of excess moisture. In such a case running an a/c more (to remove moisture from the air) would lower the temperature of the room *too* much.