# Is it even feasible to drill two 8" holes in the load bearing wall of a high rise?

Tags: load-bearing

I know this is a question for a structural engineer -- especially because this likely also need a permit from strata and even the city. But first, is there a point in starting the process?

As you [know](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/144170/how-to-get-cold-air-from-one-room-to-another) I have been trying to get my apartment air conditioned and currently have some solution but it's not great. I did find, at long last, an amazing solution, an AC and Heat Pump without the need for an outdoor unit (and the entire installation can be completed from the inside space). It requires two 8" holes drilled into the wall with their centers 12.7" apart. All my outdoor walls are concrete and very likely load bearing too.

Is it even possible a structural engineer would permit this or the hole is so big I will be laughed out of the room -- along with a several hundred dollar invoice.

Comment: It may depend on how the building is constructed. If it's a steel frame, the concrete walls are in effect just 'hung' from the steel & are not load-bearing. Whether that would persuade the local authority to allow you to fire bits of drilling waste out over 15 storeys into the public area below may require additional investigation ;)

Comment: A core drill would only have minimal debris wouldn't it? Also, it's not like the house wall runs down to the sidewalk, there's quite a bit of a green area where no one walks. I have an engineering report which says this about the exterior walls "exterior walls are comprised of formed poured-in-place concrete".

Comment: Depends on the location really. Even though concrete walls tend to be monolithic slabs there are regions where compression and tension are higher. If the latter is the case, there will be more rebar to compensate, and cutting a hole through those would be a big no no. Outside of that... I'm not sure, that requires both more detailed information on the structure as a whole, knowledge of local building code etc. You might have to consult that engineer after all.

Comment: Why wasn't the split unit an option? This would only require very small holes (mounting, ducts and electricity), negating the issues above.

Comment: There's probably a homeowner Association that would have to approve it too. If they did approve it for you, they'd have to allow it for everyone.

Comment: Would check with the city's building department and see if there are any cooling regulations(like regulations for when a building needs to supply heat).

Comment: I agree with @MiG, you found a system that *ONLY* requires two 8" holes! A split system would only require about a 1" hole for the refrigerant line.

Comment: One, I believe outside units would not be approved by city because it's unseemly. I have not seen a single one anywhere in Vancouver West End and there are 43 000 people living here -- surely many people would've already installed it if it were permissible. But of course I can ask. Also, installing the unit outside would require industrial alpinists of some kind.

Comment: What height are we talking about here? Both the building as a whole, as well as your particular floor level?

Comment: *Vancouver* - (a) there probably are some units but you just don't see them. When designed into the structure, they may not be noticeable at all from the outside of an apartment building because they can be built into walls (not protruding from the walls) or hidden on the roof (typical for large chillers). (b) I checked [the weather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver#Climate) and with *The daily maximum averages 22 °C (72 °F) in July and August, with highs rarely reaching 30 °C (86 °F)* it is not surprising that most people would *not* bother with air conditioning.

Comment: That doesn't mean *you* don't need air conditioning, and I am sure plenty of buildings (especially manufacturing, medical, etc. ) have a/c, but the average homeowner probably just opens their windows and turns on some fans for the handful of times each year that a/c would be needed. Very different from farther south.

Comment: Welcome to climate change! We had 42C last year. And starting 2025 AC will be mandatory here in new homes. The building is 22 stories and I am on the 10th story. Or so. Calculation is a bit muddled.

Comment: That's a different story altogether, both from a structural and legal perspective. I assume there's a homeowners association? The concrete outer shell of a building is almost always loadbearing, so it would definitely need an expert. I would instead raise this with the home owner association and see if there's other people interested. That would reduce cost per home as well.

Comment: @GlenYates You must have missed the part about "without the need for an outdoor unit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You will not be laughed out of the room.

---

> It requires two 8" holes drilled into the wall with their centers 12.7" apart.

Should be fine, you ever seen the size of a window?

> All my outdoor walls are concrete and very likely load bearing too.

The main worry is encountering rebar. Hire someone to come out with a GPR (ground penetrating radar). Hopefully the rebar is spaced more than 8 inches apart.

Unless you have a **very** heavy downward force directly above these 8-inch holes there is nothing to worry about.

8-inch holes are a problem in floor joists and beams since they span a great distance and have minimal/no support from below.

---

I think your main hurdle is going to be political, not physical. Good luck getting this approved by your ordinance or whoever owns your flat.

Comment: The holes are relatively small (compared to, indeed, windows), but I wouldn't recommend to going through a lot of rebar without consulting someone knowledgeable. Note that we don't know the structure of the building as a whole, or where in these walls the asker intends to punch these holes. Especially closer to corners and edges, this may not be a good idea.

Comment: @MiG I added a warning about rebar.

Comment: Appreciate it! Note that regarding your comment on the *"size of a window"*, these were there when the building was designed and therefore catered for. I agree that the holes being discussed are a lot smaller, but as we don't know the intended locations they may for example end up between a balcony door and an adjacent window, where the wall is offloading weight. I would really like to see **where** the asker intends to punch these holes before making recommendations :)

Comment: I am the owner and I wholeheartedly approve this endeavour. And I intend to make these holes wherever they can approved, I think the best would be a sheer wall about 13ft wide, no openings.

Comment: @MiG Yeah, the window statement was a bit tongue-in-cheek. Realistically, there should be a structural lintel above the window acting as a beam. Albeit the arch of a circle is going to have a lot of strength. If there exists and 8" circular lintel then I can only imagine the slimmest of chance that an engineer wouldn't approve.

Comment: @chx Well that's good. Just get it approved by your ordinance and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would be looking at cutting holes in the windows, it is doubtful that large holes will be allowed, and even less likely that you will be able to install a split system on the exterior, however the windows may be a possibility, probably not likely but a better chance than structural cuts that large on a high rise.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Ed Beal's idea, I'd consider windows in two different ways:

- Sealed Windows

If your windows are permanently sealed, as is often the case in high-rise buildings, I would not cut it at all. It is quite likely that cutting the window will result in it breaking, requiring replacement - which still won't have the desired hole. In addition, modern windows will be double (or triple) glazed, and cutting through the glass will ruin the insulating properties of the multi-layer glass. Cutting through walls (if allowed) would actually be a better choice.

- Operable Windows

If your windows can be opened, there is a better solution than cutting the window. Open the window. Cut a piece of plywood to fit the opening, cut the holes needed for the air conditioner, and mount the plywood in the opening. Secure it with tape, glue, screws - whatever works. When you move, you will be able to remove it with, at most, a few small screw holes to patch. I have actually done this myself for a dryer vent.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote, and I suspect the downvote on Ed Beal's answer as well. Window (whether direct or open + plywood) is not what OP asked, but is a plausible solution to consider under the circumstances.